# How much is the casting time of Super Tier Magic and why Ainz used a cash item to speed up Iä Shub-Niggurath spell?

Tags: overlord

I'm not sure where I have heard that is about a minute of casting time but I'm looking for some evidence to prove that statement.

**Where it was said the casting time of super tier magic and how much it is?**

Also, in the case isn't much (like a minute).
**Spoiler alert Anime 3<sup>rd</sup> season cap 12:**

> **Why does Ainz Ooal Gown used a cash item to instantly speed up the casting time of the Iä Shub-Niggurath super tier magic if no one would attack him?**
>  No one on the new world knows what is super tier magic, nor they have the necessary strength to stop him. So why he **sacrificed a cash item** that he would never recover just to cast it faster?
> If he had fear that the enemy could attack him, he could use his army to buy some (**a lot**) of time.

**PD:** I don't mind if you spoil me with anime, manga, web novel, light novel, databook, etc. I just want the answer.

Comment: I don't believe it's not mentioned in the LN, aside from the fact that the hourglass item that reduces the cast time to 0 (Overlord Volume 9, Chapter 4, Part 1). This is probably Ainz's flashiest (rather than most "powerful") so being able to activate such a powerful tier spell with all the important factions watching, adding to his "godly" image. While not a spell, but a skill, The Goal of All Life is Death has a 12 second activation time (not a cast time), and a 100 hour cooldown.

Comment: @кяαzєя 1) You could post that as an answer (about my second point), try to look cool and powerful may be a reason for Ainz. 2) I didn't understand why you mention about The Goal of All Life is Death...

Comment: It's pretty incomplete, but if you want a reference point in the LN, Super Tier spells are explained in volume 3 (chapter 4), right before the initial Fallen Down casting against Shalltear. Super tier magic are like a skill, and did not consume MP. It's the only player ability specifically mentioned with an activation time and cooldown afaik. There's a mention that there's a party wide cooldown for Super Tier spells, although long is not specifically mentioned. An average Player could only use four Super Tier spells per day at level 100. Fallen Down's CD is assumed to be 20 minutes or so.

Comment: In the anime, he made it apparent that he was looking for other PCs, so that strikes me as a valid motivation.  He laid out the bait for a little while, and then finished things up quickly to make his impression.